# Datetime null when submit a form .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, date

My model has property `TimeScheduleOnUtc` like this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}")]
public DateTime? TimeScheduleOnUtc { get; set; }
```

My form has

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" name="TimeScheduleOnUtc" />
```

But when I submit the form I always get a null value in `TimeScheduleOnUtc`. It just happened on my computer and all of my members seem they work fine. I can't find a reason why, and how can I fix. I think it may be a bug depends on date time configuration on my computer.

Comment: Tl;Dr MVC doesn't understand your date format

Comment: But you know why all of my member's computer work fine with that format

Comment: in a word Culture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your answers. Finally, I found the solution is that I need to change my datetimepicker config in my javascript from

```
        $('.datetimepicker')
            .datetimepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: new Date()
            });
```

To

```
      $('.datetimepicker')
        .datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: new Date()
        });
```

So that I change **mm** to **MM**. It works fine on my computer but maybe on your computers, it doesn't. So be careful to use it. I hope it maybe helpful for you in the future.

Comment: Is that a correct format for the minutes `ii` ? I've never seen that in `JavaScript` or `ASP .NET MVC `

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your application culture supports this date format. I had some problems with the exactly same date format. And the solutions was to set change the current culture in the `constructor` of my controller.

Try this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Additional: to check all of the supported date-time formats you can use the code from my gist [code](https://gist.github.com/M-Yankov/1cdd70ca008fc03379d81a2a67df7809) directly in your `view`

```
@{ 
    var dateInfo =  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
}
    @foreach (var item in dateInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
    {

        <div>@item</div>
    }
```

I believe there is a better approach to solve the problem, but this could be used as a workaround for now.